Best Coordinate system - Lagrangian problem

In $\Bbb R^3$ consider an heavy point $P$ whose mass $m$ on a circumference $\Gamma$ of radius $R$, centered in the origin. Now consider that $\Gamma$ lives in the plane
$$\Pi = \{( x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 : x=y \}$$
We have another point $Q$ same mass $m$ attached to the origin with a spring, $Q$ could move only on the line $\{y=z=0\}$ and is also attached with another string to $P$. Both strings has the same elastic constant. Find the Lagrangian of the system.

I'm a little bit confused on what coordinates I should choose. First thing I thought $(R,\theta)$ living in $\Pi$ plane and cartesian coordinates for $Q$
$$P = (R\cos\theta,R\sin\theta, 0)\\
Q = (0, 0, x)$$
I think it's wrong because here is like I'm forgetting that the plane is rotated of $\frac{\pi}4$, so an adjustment could be
$$P = (R\cos\theta,R\sin\theta, 0)\\
Q = \bigg(0, \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}x, \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}x\bigg)$$
Where as the last coordinate I choose the normal of $\Pi$.

Am I on the right track or missing something? Thank you very much for your help.

Actually could be a little misleading think $R$ as a coordinates because is fixed, in terms of what I've written above nothing changes but as a clarification $R$ is fixed and the "real" coordinate is $\theta$. Without $\Gamma$ I could also think at variable $R$.

Edit: Still don't know if what I've thought is correct but after a little bit of thinking spherical coordinates are a valuable choice.
Make use of the setting below

knowing that the plane $\Pi$ correspond to $\phi = \pi/4$
$$P = \bigg(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} R\sin\theta,\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} R\sin\theta, R \cos \theta\bigg)\\
Q=(r,0,0)$$
Still wondering if the method presented above works just fine...

First of all, I don’t think you should mix up spherical and Cartesian coordinates in the same problem arrangement. Second of all, the question clearly states the point $Q$ is attached at the origin. How do you get $x$ involved in the coordinates? Also, the first point you have is for some reason bound at $z=0$. How come? You know that $\Pi$ spans all the $z$-axis, don’t you?

@EgorLarionov I missed the part where $Q$ is linked to a line. The point $P$ in my new coordinate system isn't at $z=0$ since $z$ is no more a coordinate, I'm choosing the normal to the plane in the origin as last coordinate.

That’s an abuse of notation. If you say $Q=(0,0,x)$, then it’s not a point.

@EgorLarionov what do you mean it's not a point? Could you elaborate further? Notation abuse left apart, related to my question do you have any thoughts?

What I would do is start off with the $P$. To parametrise the circumference I would add a constant vector $\mathbf{r}_0=(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to the circumference, parametrised by the unit vectors within the plane $x=y$.
Let's proceed to choosing this vectors. Since they might be chosen arbitrarily, I would choose $\mathbf{p}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0\right)$, which is a vector collinear to the line $x=y$, and $\mathbf{q}=\left(0, 0, 1\right)$, which goes along $z$-axis. Now, since I want my circumference to lie on the plane spanned by these two vectors, any point on it should satisfy the following equation for some $\theta$:
$$
\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{p}R\cos\theta+\mathbf{q}R\sin\theta
$$
What's left is to move the circumference away from the origin to its center by adding the $\mathbf{r}_0$. Finally, the position of $P$ at any given time could be parametrised by:
$$
\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{p}R\cos\theta+\mathbf{q}R\sin\theta + \mathbf{r}_0
$$
or equivalently:
$$
\mathbf{r}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_0 +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}R\cos\theta \\
y_0 +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}R\cos\theta \\
z_0 + R\sin\theta 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $x_0 = y_0$.

Ok I get what you're trying to do in rotating the coordinate to fit the circumference. My thought is, wouldn't work the same if i'm rotating the axe where $Q$ live? For the circumference I would use usual polar coordinates and I will apply a reasoning similar to yours for the rotated axe. Why I will go the other way round? To me seems easier honestly...
